# LINQ: How to select entire list of list by certain object property value

Tags: c#, list, linq

It is probably an easy one but i could not find an answer.
I have `List<List<myclass>>`, how can i extract **entire** List by a specific value object property value?

for example, please see my draft code, how can i extract the entire (all the objects in that list) `t2` List based on `mc7` object properties?

I am only succeeding to extract `mc7`object but not the List of it in `result` variable.

```
class myclass
{
    public DateTime SomeDate;
    public string SomeString;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<List<myclass>> L = new List<List<myclass>>();
    List<myclass> t = new List<myclass>();

    myclass mc = new myclass() { SomeString = "5", SomeDate = DateTime.Now};
    myclass mc1 = new myclass() { SomeString = "12", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };
    myclass mc2 = new myclass() { SomeString = "123", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) };
    myclass mc3 = new myclass() { SomeString = "77", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) };
    myclass mc4 = new myclass() { SomeString = "882", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) };

    t.Add(mc);
    t.Add(mc1);
    t.Add(mc2);
    t.Add(mc3);
    t.Add(mc4);

    L.Add(t);

    List<myclass> t2 = new List<myclass>();

    myclass mc5 = new myclass() { SomeString = "166", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(500) };
    myclass mc6 = new myclass() { SomeString = "344", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(501) };
    myclass mc7 = new myclass() { SomeString = "123", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(502) };
    myclass mc8 = new myclass() { SomeString = "234", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(503) };
    myclass mc9 = new myclass() { SomeString = "123", SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(504) };

    t2.Add(mc5);
    t2.Add(mc6);
    t2.Add(mc7);
    t2.Add(mc8);
    t2.Add(mc9);

    L.Add(t2);

    var target1 = "123";
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(502).Date;

    var result = L.SelectMany(x => x)
        .Where(y => y.SomeString == target1 && y.SomeDate.Date == date).Select(x=>x).ToList();

}
```

Comment: I don't get why you want the `t2`-list because it's empty. I guess the latter `t.Add` should be `t2.Add`. Do you want the whole list or only the list containing all objects that match?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it was a mistake, it is t2 and now it is not empty, thank you.

Comment: @mjwills result should be `t2` entire list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the lists which contain at least one object that match your predicate:

```
var result = L.Where(list => list.Any(x => x.SomeString == target1 && x.SomeDate.Date == date)).ToList();
```

If you want only one list, replace the `ToList` with `FirstOrDefault`.

If you want the lists which contain at least one object that match your predicate and those list should only contain those objects, so all other non-matching objects are filtered out:

```
var result = L
    .Select(list => list.Where(x => x.SomeString == target1 && x.SomeDate.Date == date).ToList())
    .Where(list => list.Any())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you but it is not working, i need all the members of `t2` list

Comment: @jonathana: the first way returns all members of T2, so 5 objects

Comment: @jonathana: here is a dotnet.fiddle which shows that it's working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IJ4rab

Comment: I apologize!! it returns 5 results. i forgot to change something important in the code....

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the usage of `SelectMany` since you are searching for a specific list:

```
var result = L
     .Where(l=>l.Any(y => y.SomeString == target1 && y.SomeDate.Date == date))
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it returns 10 results of the 2 lists (it should be 5 as the length of `t2`)

Comment: yes i am sure, maybe its because `SomeString = "123"` is existing also in `mc2` object?

Comment: I apologize! it returns 5 results.